# Iterate to combine legend handles and labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

If I have the following plotting routine that plots a scatter plot and corresponding linear regression and combines the legend handles:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import linregress
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#data and Regression
x = np.arange(0,5,1)
y = np.arange(0,10,2)
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'x':x,'y':y})
s, intcpt, r, p, serr = linregress(df.x, df.y)
xHat = np.linspace(0,5,100)


# do the plotting
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(x='x',y='y',ax=ax,label='series1',ls=' ',marker='x',c='blue')
ls_handle, = ax.plot(xHat, s*xHat + intcpt, linestyle='-', marker=None, c='blue')
handle2merge = [ls_handle]
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handle_combined = zip(handles, handle2merge)
ax.legend(handle_combined, labels)
```

Which returns the where the marker and line handles are merged looking like:

[image]

Now I want to plot another dataset in a similar fashion:

```
#get current axis handles and labels
handle_start, label_start = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

#second dataset and regression
x1 = np.arange(0,5,1)
y1 = np.arange(0,2.5,0.5)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'x':x1,'y':y1})
s1, intcpt1, r1, p1, serr1 = linregress(df1.x, df1.y)
xHat1 = np.linspace(0,5,100)

#plot second data set on same figure
marker_handle2, = ax.plot(df1.x, df1.y, marker = 'x', zorder=10,c='k', linestyle=' ')
line_handle2, = ax.plot(xHat, s1*xHat1 + intcpt1, linestyle='--', marker=None, c='k') 
new_line_handles = [line_handle2]
new_marker_handles= [marker_handle2]

ax.legend(handle_start + zip(new_marker_handles,new_line_handles), label_start + ['series2'])
```

This returns a plot where the handles for `series1` legend handle only contains the marker.

[image]

Why is `len(handle_start)=1` when I constructed the handle with `handle_combined = zip(handles, handle2merge)`?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to plot the markers and lines separately?

Comment: @gmds yes, the data are constructed at different times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have poked around the code a little. What you are doing is passing a `list` of `tuples` to `ax.legend`, which apparently draws each Artist in each `tuple` as one entry in the legend. I have actually not come across this behaviour before; it could be a bug, or unintended use of `ax.legend`.

Nevertheless, I think that in this case, since you know what your lines should look like beforehand, instead of going the roundabout way with `zip` and stuff, you could just pass a custom `Line2D` to `legend` directly:

```
import numpy as np

from scipy.stats import linregress

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import lines

x1 = np.arange(0, 5, 1)
y1 = np.arange(0, 10, 2)
x2 = np.arange(0, 5, 1)
y2 = np.arange(0, 2.5, 0.5)

m1, c1, r1, p1, serr1 = linregress(x1, y1)
m2, c2, r2, p2, serr2 = linregress(x2, y2)

x_pred = np.linspace(0,5,100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

first_line, = ax.plot(x_pred, x_pred * m1 + c1, ls='-', c='blue')
first_scatter = ax.scatter(x1, y1, marker='x', c='blue')

second_line, = ax.plot(x_pred, x_pred * m2 + c2, ls='--', c='black')
second_scatter = ax.scatter(x2, y2, marker='x', c='black')

ax.legend([lines.Line2D([0], [0], marker='x', ls='-', c='blue'),
           lines.Line2D([0], [0], marker='x', ls='--', c='black')],
          ['series_1', 'series_2'])
```

[image]

I cleaned up your code a little, but feel free to take only the last line and the necessary import.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it and suggesting a viable workaround.  It seems buggy to me too!  I will submit a github issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line, just use the already created merged handle `handle_combined` instead of the `handle_start`.

```
ax.legend(handle_combined + list(zip(new_marker_handles,new_line_handles)), 
          label_start + ['series2'])
```

The length is 1 but if you look into the contents of the list, it is a tuple consisting of two objects. If you print `handle_combined`, you get a list of two `Line2D` objects, one of which is marker and the other is the line.

```
print (handle_combined)
# [(<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at xxxxxxxxx>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at xxxxxxxxx>)]
```

---

However, if you print `handle_start`, it returns just a single `Line2D` object

```
print (handle_start)
# [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at xxxxxxxxx>]
```

[image]

Comment: Good point.  I will revise my question to ask why the second element of the tuple disappears upon the second call of `ax.get_legend_handles_labels`